# Difference-in-Differences time period

Tags: difference-in-difference

does the time periods in my difference in differences analysis need to be the same for both periods?

Say I have an event at a specific date (new policy), does t=1 need to have the same length (e.g. 6 months before specific date) as t=2 (e.g. 6 months after specific date)? Or does this not matter? Would it make more sense to look at a different time frame? I have a relatively large data set.

Thanks!